# Are pixels not squares and more like rectangles?

Tags: computer-engineering, computer

When I open Paint, I change the size to 500x500. It appears more as a rectangle than a square. Has anyone else had this happen? Is there an explanation? Not sure if this is a thing that differs on different computers.

Comment: It is possible that your display has a nonsquare aspect ratio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a square to me - are you sure you selected the pixel checkmark, and also unchecked the "Maintain aspect ratio" box before typing in your second '500'?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Yes, I did those things. What I mean is, if you set the resolution to 500x500, then measure it physically with a ruler. My result was that it is taller than wider.

Comment: I have edited my answer to include real-world photos.

Comment: Interesting, must be something that differs then.